# Does Star Trek solve the Mind-Body problem?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter

For those of you who are unaware of the mind-body problem, it is basically trying to determine how the mind connects with the body, and can lead on to 'what is the mind' and whether it is a physical object (note - this refers to the *mind* not the brain).  As in Star Trek, one can use the transporters to transport a person from one position to another, and the person is perfectly intact, this implies that Star Trek solves the mind-body problem.  Is this the case and, if so, what is the solution to it?

Comment: I'm not sure about Star Trek, but our mind, consciousness, 'soul' or whatever you want to call it appears to be simply an emergent property of our (very advanced) brains.

Comment: @Kvothe: The evidence on that is still somewhat subjective, unfortunately. I tend to agree with you, but I'm unwilling to flat-out state it.

Comment: Tuvix and Thomas Riker would suggest that the mind body problem is a huge issue in transporter ethics

Comment: @Richard - never mind "Search for Spock"

Comment: There is no evidence of a mind existing without a body (or brain). There is no mind-body "problem".

Comment: @Gelfamat: Does Q have a body?

Comment: Irrelevant. Q is not human so aspects of his existence would not be helpful in trying to explain the human condition.

Comment: @Kvothe  I read in a philosophy of the mind book, that the problem with stating that the mind is an emergent property of the brain, is that emergent properties aren't meant to be or supposedly cannot be causative. So, if the mind can cause the body to act, then the mind isn't an emergent property.

Comment: @barlop: Who says emergent properties can't cause things? Why can't they? One must be careful about things found in Philosophy books; generally speaking, books that are well-grounded in logic or evidence are called Mathematics or Science books.

Comment: @Beta good point, and trying to look it up i've now found there is a term philosophers use called "causally emergent property" so yeah it can be according to them too!

Comment: There is a consciousness vs. body distinction.

Comment: @Gelfamat:   What about "Lonely Among Us":   **First Officer's log, supplemental. More than an hour has passed since the Captain beamed out, energy only.**

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2024/3804

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Star Trek embraces whatever philosophy is required to tell the current story.

1. In the TOS episode "The Lights of Zetar" *Enterprise* encounters extant members of a dead civilization who existed for millennia as acorporeal minds searching for a suitable body in which to live out the remainder of their corporeal lives.  This is an example of Cartesian or substance dualism.
2. In the TNG episode "The Schizoid Man" cyberneticist Ira Graves flees his dying body and causes his mind to run on a new substrate, the positronic brain and body of Lt. Cmdr. Data.  This is an example of monism, in particular, physicalism.
3. On *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, we learn on the existence of the Prophets, acorporeal entities that exist at least partly outside time itself, though they do inhibit material bodies from time to time.  This is (probably) an example of idealistic monism.
4. In the TOS episode "Turnabout Intruder", Janice Lester swaps ids with Captain Kirk, inhabiting his body while he inhabited hers.  Substance dualism again.
5. In the TOS episode "What Are Little Girls Made Of?" Roger Corby transfers his mind to run on a new substrate: an android body.  Physicalism again.
6. In the movie *The Search for Spock* we learn that Spock's *katra*, whatever that is, was deposited into Dr. McCoy to be later extracted by some mystical process.  This is an example of property dualism.

If there's a mind-body philosophy that Star Trek has not yet embraced, give them time.

Comment: Another example would be TNG [Lonely Among us](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Lonely_Among_Us_%28episode%29) where various members of the crew are inhabited by an energy being, and Picard becomes an energy being for a short time.

Comment: Also note TNG [Second Chances](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Second_Chances_(episode)) in which a transporter malfunction splits Riker into two identical copies in different places, both of whom believe themselves to be whole and original.

Comment: Not knowing the terms you use, which one would [Our Man Bashir](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Our_Man_Bashir_(episode)) fall under?

Comment: Tangentally related, you could argue that the Borg Hive mind suppresses the individual mind to act through many beings. From VOY we learn that Seven was part of a community of Borg individuals whom could communicate when their bodies were regenerating (Unimatrix Zero), i.e. 'suppression' rather than 'replacement' of the mind from the body

Comment: And I recall *First Contact* where the Bork queen says: *You think in such 3-dimentional terms* when Picard says that the ship she was on was destroyed.

Comment: In "What Are Little Girls Made Of?" one could argue that the Roger Corby android is not, in fact, Roger Corby, but an android who *thinks* it's Roger Corby.

Answer (score 6):

Star Trek's transporters use "[Heisenberg Compensators](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Heisenberg_compensator)" to circumvent the [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) that should prevent such devices from working (according to our current understanding of physics). It is quite likely that those same compensators account for the mind-body divide, though this is merely speculation on my part. One would imagine a culture that deals with telepathy on a regular basis would have far greater understanding of the Mind-Body Problem than our current society; if so, however, this has never been explored by the series in any medium.

Comment: I haven't figured out if the transporter is actually *teleporting* a crewmember, or destroying their original body and recreating an exact copy at the destination, or simply *moving* the crewmember through subspace (sort of like a wormhole or an FTL mini-jump)? The last explanation avoids mind-body philosophical issues.

Comment: @RobertF: I vaguely remember at least one episode where a person was able to be brought back into existence because their pattern was still in the transporter's memory.  That would suggest it's disassembling and reassembling.

Comment: I bet you're thinking of the TNG S6E04 epsiode "Relics" where Scotty's pattern is recovered from the transporter's memory banks. Although you could also argue that Scotty wasn't disassembled & reassembled - rather he "wormholed" through subspace from the past to the future.

Comment: @RobertF there is also [Realm of Fear](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Realm_of_Fear_(episode)) where the crew of the USS Yosemite is rescued from the transporter stream.

Comment: The bane of *Stack Exchange*; the unexplained downvote :(.

Comment: @RobertF I recall reading (though I don't know if it's canon or not) that different versions of the transporters actually did different things as technology advanced - some (I believe the earlier ones) destroying the original, others (later ones) actually moving the crew member's disassembled parts.

Answer (score 4):

The book "Is Data Human? The Metaphysics of Star Trek" goes into vaguely similar problems involving the transporters and issues of whether the person after the transport is the same person as the person before the transport, i.e. if who comes out of the transport is just a near-perfect copy of the person went in.

All I think we can gather from the existence of working transporters is that a perfect replication of a person's physical form results in their "mind" being identical. Whether that's because the mind exists physically within the body (which I don't personally believe) or the mind is an emergent property of the brain (which I do personally believe) isn't really answered either way.

Answer (score 3):

I think overall "Star Trek" is pretty dualistic.  People all have energy based souls, though they don't use the word.  Those souls can be pulled out of people, and hang free as energy, or jump to other bodies...they aren't tied to the function of a particular piece of meat.  In theory, transporters should be able to make copies of people, but they don't do this, and no matter the technobabble explanation, the overarching universe rule is that transporters shouldn't be able to make souls.  And with the exception of Thomas Riker, they don't.

Comment: Transporters can make Riker's soul?

Comment: @Dronz Uh oh... did you just uncover a startling fact about Riker?

Comment: Perhaps Thomas Riker has no soul.

Answer (score 1):

People with telekinesis get their abilities through structures in their brains (IIRC!). It stands to reason that the mind-body problem is also solved through such structures.

It is my understanding that spirits live in another "dimension" in Star Trek. A world in which spiritual energy and such exist more or less freely. There is the episode with body-controlling wisps, and the series of episodes about Wesley and the traveller that seem to support such a theory. This is however describing the mind.

There is no explicit mention of what ties such a mind to a body, but by extension of the telekinects being a property of the brain we can say that the brain has structures such that it ties the mind to the body. This is the most realistic explanation that still allows everything canon to be as it is.

Note: the Riker accident tells us that the mind is (in spacial..space) located where the body is, for the reflection and duplication to take place as it did. Alternatively the accident caused quite a stir in the world of spirits (like Q) and they replicated his spirit to cause the humans not to stumble upon such outlandish principles. (Q other extraspacial beings replicated Riker's soul to prevent confusion among humans for whatever purpose, possibly improved observation like Q's species likes to do)

It can take some mental gymnastics to work out solutions for nearly every episode. A flexible single approach as given above helps you do it :)

Comment: Now that I re-read it I remember that Q was always "testing" humanity to see if they were "worthy". It would make sense to avoid their discovery of Q's realm. It would be as if humanity found a way to bypass the pearly gates and walk straight into heaven (tower of Babylon story).

Comment: Also, Riker was not the only crew member replicated... Voyager's entire crew was replicated more than once (although in different ways); if I recall, one episodes basically establishes that the only "original" crew member that survived was Harry Kim, the rest were duplicates.