# How does Data's computation ability compare to the Enterprise's?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Can the ship perform more calculations per second since it is much larger and is not confined to the size of an average human? Or is the ship actually a distributed network of many computers specialized for specific tasks, thus making the two difficult to objectively compare?

Comment: Enterprise has more storage, but Data is better at Computation.

Comment: @SachinShekhar  That's what I suspected too, but do you have any sources to confirm it?

Comment: i haven't found anything that actually goes into detail about the enterprises computers computing powers, however on memory alpha it does give how many computations data can do and its an extremely large number lol, the computers in startrek were only vaguely talked about so as they would not seem dated in the future.

Comment: Data's operations are described in operations per second (60 gigaflops) whereas the Enterprise' operations are described in a fictional measure called quads. I'll be pleasantly surprised if you can find a source that allows you to compare them directly.

Comment: You can compare Data to the Voyager computer. Basically he's a pocket calculator by comparison.

Comment: I didn't think we allowed Mac vs. Windows questions. ;)

Comment: There is no direct comparison of Data's computational capacity and the Enterprise's. Trust me, I looked. The closest comparison we could find was to Voyager's computation capacity and data wasn't even in the same league. Data is powerful but Voyager' neural network left him in the dust. Take a look at [The Moriarty Problem](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73423/2765) for the comparison.

Comment: Voyager's computer was capable of 575 trillion calculations per NANOSECOND (or the equivalent of 575,000,000,000 petaflops per seccond), compared with Commander Data's rated processor speed of 60 petaflops per second and the estimated Human brain comparison of 2.2 billion megaflops per second. (REF: Fischetti, Mark. "Computers vs Brains" Scientificamerican.com. N.p. Web. 25 Nov. 2014.)

Comment: @Richard: The unit of quads is usually referenced to indicate storage capacity, not computation capacity/operations per time.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Alas, they seem to be used interchangeably, making the distinction largely meaningless. In this case, the writing was intended to obscure, not to illuminate.

Comment: @Richard: Based upon quotes such as ["converted into billions of kiloquads of data"](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/228.htm), ["Your programme's too large for the datastream. (...) Twelve megaquads."](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/622.htm), or ["twenty million gigaquads of new information"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/118.htm), as well as the MA definition that ["a quad was a measurement of information storage"](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Quad), I tend to disagree with this claim, but further discussion would rather fit into a separate question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I'll accept that. Thaddeus' figures above seem pretty conclusive.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze: Units like "petaflops per second" or "megaflops per second" do not make much sense, given that "flops" is already a measurement per time (floating point operations *per second*). Also, the [article you seem to refer to](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/computers-vs-brains/) is from November 1, 2011, not November 25, 2014.

Comment: Data had a positronic brain. The Enterprise ran a mainframe. Data wins, case closed.

Comment: @Solo "Enterprise has more storage, but Data is better at Computation." So the computer has more data, but Data is better at computing?

Comment: @Acccumulation Yeah, Star Trek is a mess.. :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Interestingly, there is an episode where the ship and Data directly interact with one another on a digital scale - [A Fistful of Datas](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/A_Fistful_of_Datas_(episode)).

In this episode, Georgi and Data attempt to connect Data to the Enterprise's main computer, so that in the event of an emergency Data could take full control of the Enterprise.

Their experiment goes remarkably well, until Data tries to access the ship's secondary systems.  Data detects an overload in his positronic matrix and shuts the experiment down, but the damage is done in the form of a Texas-Talkin' Data, as well as Data being represented in several parts of the ship (most notably, as several characters on the Holodeck).

Up until that point though, Data was able to access individual parts of the system and operate them.  The sudden surge, however, suggests that some systems may be too complex for him to handle.  And the fact that he was accessing systems one at a time also lends credit to suggest the Enterprise's computer is larger and more complex than Data's brain can handle all at once.

This may also indicate a limit on Data's ability to multi-task as well as the ship computer, or that there is simply an incompatibility between the two.  Unfortunately, there is no way to tell, because the series does not do a particularly deep analysis into the ship's data processing power.

Comment: or that the ships systems where to crude for data's brain to handle.

Comment: I think, if anything, the incident seems to indicate that the ship's computer has a greater ability to multi-task than Data's positronic brain does. That doesn't necessarily indicate computing ability as much as... well, I guess we'd call it "thread capacity" or "bandwidth".

Comment: The thing is, they wouldn't have attempted to do the experiment, especially using their *second officer* as a Guinea pig, if they hadn't done the math first. They must have had a reasonable expectation that it would work.

Comment: @JohnSensebe You'd think that, but you'd also think they would review basic societal protocols before visiting alien planets, and they *never* do.  (realistically, they probably didn't have any means to measure the impact, because Data's own brain is so unique in this universe).

Answer (score 4):

In TNG S03E06, "Booby Trap," Geordi suggests that not even Commander Data could perform as many adjustments per second as the ship's computer (in the form of a holographic projection of one of the original Enterprise's warp core designers).

Answer (score 0):

***Regarding Voyager's secondary processor, 575 trillion calculations per nanosecond is actually 575,000 exaflops - with each of these 575,000 exaflops about equivalent to a human brain.  In contrast, with 60 petaflops (0.06 exaflops), Data's positronic brain would only be about the equivalent of one mouse brain.***

Note from wiki:Exascale computing refers to computing systems capable of at least one exaFLOPS, or a billion billion (i.e. a quintillion) calculations per second. Such capacity represents a thousandfold increase over the first petascale computer that came into operation in 2008.[1] (One exaflop is a thousand petaflops or a quintillion, 1018, double precision floating point operations per second)..., and Exascale computing would be a significant achievement in computer engineering, as an exascale computer would have processing power on the order of the estimated processing power of the human brain at the neural level (although the functional power required to simulate a human brain might be lower).

Comment: Is this a quote from somewhere? Or what's your source?

Answer (score -1):

I am sure that I remember reading in the ST tech manual that all federation ships central computer processor core are held inside of a static warp bubble (hence making them FTL processors), secondary interface sub systems run at less than FTL, (pads control panels etc)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anything like this. Could you rummage up a source? (There is this one that Riker made up http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/FTL_nanoprocessor - it has 25 bilateral kelilactirals!)

Answer (score -2):

It was mentioned on Voyager by its own computer that it has transluminal processing.
This implies from the wording alone that the main computer processor is FTL based...

And since most (or practically all) technology on a Federation ship is subspace based, even computers would effectively be using subspace principles.

It never made any sense that the Federation was unable to create its own Androids.
Heck, given the rate of exponential progression, androids with more processing power than Data will be possible shortly in reality... 
Star Trek missed the mark on 'exponential development' aspect especially when it had various aliens for example being better at translation than it... that's just impossible.
No organic entity would be able to process things faster than a computer... a computer simply needs a proper set of algorithms to work with... and while those used in Trek seemed advanced, they also seemed outdated in comparison to the hardware's capabilities.

Comment: This barely seems to answer the question

Comment: Directly from Voyager:
TAU: Computer, tell us your technical specifications. 
COMPUTER: Simultaneous access to forty seven million data channels. Transluminal processing at five hundred seventy five trillion calculations per nanosecond. 

It's not a big stretch to think 'transluminal processing' means FTL and subspace based... or essentially, faster than light.

Similar wording is exacted in Trek FTL terminology for Transwarp (indicating 'faster than warp').
Don't understand which part of my answer merits -1

Comment: Because you've not answered the question asked.